# Why do I get a time limit exceeded on SPOJ classical problem 5?

Tags: java, palindrome

I supposedly have a 9 second time limit but when I run 2 numbers with close to one million digits on NetBeans it takes 5 seconds to output. My isPalindrome  method compares symmetrical digits (1st and last, 2nd and 2nd last etc...) and edits the number according to the following rules:

1. If the digit to the left(1st digit, 2nd digit etc...) is larger than the digit to the right(last digit, 2nd last digit etc...), make the digit on the right match the digit on the left (9113 ---> 9119)
2. If the digit on the left is smaller than the digit on the right, make the digit on the right match the digit on the left but increase the values of the digits next to the digit on the right (3987 ---> 3993 or 8999 ---> 9008 or 
   7899 ---> 7907)

I keep my number through these rules until I find a palindrome.

To summarize my question(s) is: Why do I get a time limit exceeded error when on NetBeans my program runs in the given time frame?

public class SPOJ5 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private static final String counter = "01234567890";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t;
    BigInteger addNum;
    List<BigInteger> k = new ArrayList();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        try {
            t = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            t = 2;
        }
    } while (t < 0);

    do {
        try {
            addNum = new BigInteger(in.next());
            addNum = addNum.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            if (digitCount(addNum) < 999999) {
                k.add(addNum);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            k.add(BigInteger.valueOf(9).pow(100));
        }
        t--;
    } while (t > 0);

    for (BigInteger num : k) {
        int digits = digitCount(num);
        int middleNum;
        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder(num.toString());

        if (digits % 2 == 0) {
            middleNum = digits / 2;
            number = new StringBuilder(num.toString());

            number = isPalindrome(number, digits - 1, count, middleNum);

        } else {
            middleNum = digits / 2;
            number = isPalindrome(number, digits - 1, count, middleNum + 1);
        }

        System.out.println(number);

    }
}

public static StringBuilder isPalindrome(StringBuilder number, int lastDigitIndex, int firstDigitIndex, int middleNum) {
    while (lastDigitIndex >= middleNum) {

        if (number.charAt(firstDigitIndex) != number.charAt(lastDigitIndex)) {

            if (counter.indexOf(number.charAt(firstDigitIndex)) > counter.indexOf(number.charAt(lastDigitIndex))) {
                number.replace(lastDigitIndex, lastDigitIndex + 1, Character.toString(number.charAt(firstDigitIndex)));
                firstDigitIndex++;
                lastDigitIndex--;
            } else {
                number.replace(lastDigitIndex, lastDigitIndex + 1, Character.toString(number.charAt(firstDigitIndex)));

                do {
                    number.replace(lastDigitIndex - 1, lastDigitIndex, Character.toString(counter.charAt(counter.indexOf(number.charAt(lastDigitIndex - 1)) + 1)));
                    lastDigitIndex--;
                } while ((Character.toString(counter.charAt(counter.indexOf(number.charAt(lastDigitIndex)))).equals("0")));

                lastDigitIndex = number.length() - 1;
                firstDigitIndex = 0;
            }
        } else {
            firstDigitIndex++;
            lastDigitIndex--;
        }

    }
    return number;
}

public static int digitCount(BigInteger bi) {
    String s = bi.toString();
    return s.length();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the runtime environment of the host running your code? VM flags, VM version, and what not?

Comment: Have you tested your code on corner cases given in problem statement?

Comment: @Ivan yes I copy and pasted the decimal values from 1million digits of PI website

Comment: @yorodm No, I don't know how to do that. SPOJ lets you check your code through Ideone is that it?

Comment: You do too many unnecessary string conversions.